# Handling uniqueness in a multi-tenant Django setup

Tags: django, django-models, multi-tenant

I ahve a multi tenant Django database. All my multi tenant enabled models import from a class `AccountSpecificModel`, which as a FK to a class `Account`. Now I have some `unique=True` and `unqiue_together` in `Meta`, which do not specify `account`.

In my scenario, for `AccountSpecificModel` uniqueness has no menaing unless it takes care of `account`, which means I want to convert each `unique` to a `unique_together` with `account`, and simlar for `unique_together`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is what you want:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('account', 'email'),)
```

Notice the "two-tuple" I assigned unique_together to. You can do a standard tuple, but if there is more than one field that you want to be unique together, you'll just have to change it anyway.

Now 500 different accounts can have a client with the email example@example.com, but no account can have 2 clients with the same email.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question fully, but I found that when implementing complicated django model class customizations one good solution is a class factory. I found that it is less complicated and less surprising than multiple inheritance and other magic.

```
def factory(superclass, arguments):
    class SomeClass(superclass):
        [...]

        class Meta:
            [...]

    return SomeClass

RealClass = factory(SuperClass, args)
```

I tried other approaches on a similar sounding problem for a while, but a factory for the class solved the problem in the end. Think about it, it may help you to solve your problem.